# sql time offset

Tags: sql, oracle, time, timezone-offset

new to sql and learning about time offsets and faced with a whole load of complicated information. what I have is

**Table: test history**

```
Columns: start_time( timestamp)
         end_time   (timestamp)
```

I have to show the time those tests were taken with a time offset showing the time in 2 other time zones.
I am seeing information like this:

```
 ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-8:0';
```

but how did I talk specifically about these columns?
is it something like this?

```
select start_time
from test_history
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-8:0';
```

Comment: what database are you using? mysql or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you start from a `timestamp` you can try:

```
 SELECT from_tz(start_date,'+01:00') at TIME ZONE '-07:00' from myTable;
```

The example assumes that your Oracle database is set to work with a local time zone equal to `+01:00 (GMT+1)` (check it with `select DBTIMEZONE from dual;`) :

Another way would be to change the time zone before executing the query;:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='-07:00';
SELECT start_date from myTable;
```